# Why is Composer not updating my /vendor folder with requirements from my composer.json file?

Tags: php, composer-php

My `composer.json` file is pretty simple, just requiring Twig and a PHP version number like so:

```
{
  "name": "name-here",
  "type": "wordpress-plugin",
  "require": {
    "twig/twig": "^2.0"
  },
  "autoload":{
    "psr-4": {
      "namespace-name-here\\" : "./"
    }
  }
}
```

Yet when I run `composer dump-autoload` it only creates the `/vendor/composer` directory. In my other projects, the `/twig` and /`symfony` directories are creating from my `composer.json` file. So I have to copy the two missing directories into my project to work.

What am I missing here? I delete the entire `/vendor` directory and re-run the `composer dump-autoload` command and still the same result.

Comment: use `composer install` to install packages. 
use `composer dump-autoload` to dump a new autoload file for _installed_ packages. Typically used in combination with `composer install --no-autoloader`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use composer install.